# Approximating step functions with polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

Let $t_1 < t_2 < \cdots <t_m$ be real, and $X = \cup_{i=1}^{m-1} (t_i, t_{i+1})$ be a union of real open intervals.  Let $f:X \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$ be any piecewise constant function of form
$$
f(x) = 
    \begin{cases} 
      a_1 & \text{ if } t_1 < x < t_2 \\
      a_2 & \text{ if }t_2 < x < t_3 \\
      \vdots \\
a_{m-2} & \text{ if } t_{m-2} < x < t_{m-1} \\ 
      a_{m-1} & \text{ if } t_{m-1} < x < t_m 
   \end{cases}
$$
Where $a_i \in \{-1, 1\}$, and $a_{i} = -a_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, ..., m-1$.

I have a number of questions regarding polynomial approximations of such a function $f$:

1. Can we always find a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ so that $(p_n)$ converge pointwise to $f$, AND we have some fixed (not arbitrary) global error bound, say $1$, such that $|p_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in X$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$?
2. If so, are such polynomials easy to find?
3. How quickly do we get convergence?

I am aware that, upon picking a suitable inner product, we can use any collection of orthonormal polynomials to make approximations of functions.  For example I know the Chebyshev, Bernstein, Jacobi etc. polynomials can be used to approximate continuous functions on bounded intervals, but I have found no theorem that says we can use these to construct approximations for arbitrary piecewise constant functions like the one given above.

Indeed, it is easy to find a polynomial approximation for the Heaviside Step function for example, however it is unclear how, or if this an be done for more complicated step functions.

Comment: I can suggest Bernstein-form polynomials.  Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514675/is-there-a-canonical-probabilistic-version-of-the-step-function/517698#517698 . However I don't believe discontinuous functions can achieve the error bound for all $x$, as opposed to continuous functions.  See, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/523261/296678

Comment: If $P(x)$ exists so that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $|P(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ then, $P(x) = f(x)$, so $P(x)$ is not a polynomial.  I think you have your quantifiers in the wrong order.

Comment: Since the open intervals are disjoint, you can connect the function on those intervals by diagonal lines to produce a continuous function you want to approximate.

Comment: @TomKern No, the open intervals share a boundary point, so you cannot do this.

Comment: Related paper: Totik, V., 2020. "Polynomials close to 0 resp. 1 on disjoint sets". Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 482(2), p.123549.

Comment: @PeterO. helpful comment, thank you.

Comment: @GEG won't $|p_n(x)-f(x)|$ get as large as $1$? $p_n$ will have to have some roots to well-approximate $f$...

Comment: @mathworker21 I am restricting to the set $X$, so $|p_n(x)-f(x)|$ won't get as large as 1 for $x \in X$ (in theory, this is what I am asking about).

Comment: @GEG $X$ is basically connected... u want the bound for a fixed $n$. no way ur gonna get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, there do exist such polynomials, and in fact we can construct them in a way that they converge to the step function at an exponential rate.  We can do this by defining polynomial one-dimensional maps with an unstable fixed point and an attracting period two orbit.  The iteration of this map then converges to the period two orbit, so we can iterate this map over an appropriate polynomial, to achieve the approximation we desire.

See the papers https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3765 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604324 for complete study of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The given step function can be presented in the form of
$$f(x)=(-1)^m a^\ _1\operatorname{sgn}y(x),\quad\text{where}\quad y(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}(x-t_j).\tag1$$
Function $\,\operatorname{sgn}z\,$ can be presented via [Fourier series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%5Bsum_%28n%3D1%20to%2020%29%20%284%20x%20sinc%28%282n-1%29pi%20x%29%29%5D%2C%20%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D) in the form of
$$\operatorname{sgn}z=\dfrac 4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin((2n-1)\pi z)}{2n-1},\tag2$$
[image: Fourier approximation, n=20]
(n=1...20)

where the sine functions are the polynomials of $\,\sin \pi z:\,$
$$\sin((2n-1)\pi z)=P_{2n-1}(\sin \pi z),\tag3$$
$$P_{2n-1}(t) = t\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^j\dbinom{2n-2-j}j(4-4t^2)^{n-1-j}.\tag4$$

Therefore,
$$\operatorname{sgn}z=\dfrac4\pi\,\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac1{2n-1}P_{2n-1}(\sin \pi z).\tag5$$
Since the function $\operatorname{sgn} z$ has the gap in the point $\,z=0,\,$ then attempt of transformation of formulas $(5)$ to the polynomial series leads to the divergent expressions for the coefficients.
However, looks **possible** to build the polynomial approximation of the function $f(x)$ as the polynomial sequence $\,f_N(x),\,$ based on the formulas $(1),(4),(5)$ and the known Maclaurin series for $\,\sin \pi z.\,$

The optimization task solution (via logarithmic derivative) gives
$$Y=\max\limits_{x\in(t_1,t_m)} |y(x)|=\max(|y(x_l)|,|y(x_h)|),\tag6$$
where
$$\dfrac1{x_l-t_1}=\prod_{j=2}^{m-1}\dfrac1{t_j-x_l},\quad x_l\in(t_1,t_2)\tag7$$
and
$$\dfrac1{x_h-t_{m-1}} = \prod_{j=1}^{m-2}\dfrac1{x_h-t_j},\quad x_h\in(t_{m-1}, t_m).\tag8$$
Then
$$\operatorname{sgn}(y(x)) = \operatorname{sgn} z(x),\quad\text{where}\quad z(x)=\dfrac {y(x)}Y,\quad |z(x)|\le1.\tag9$$
Applying of $\,z(x)\,$ instead $\,y(x)\,$ in $(1)$ allows to control the calculation accuracy of the sine function and finally - the required distances of the given function gaps, which provide the required calculation accuracy of the approximations $f_N(x)$.